# Feature file grouping -Testing in js

Tags: testing, cucumber

I am new in testing. I have multiple features files and all feature file has common test case written for login with credentials. Is there any way for writing the test case for logging into page in a single feature file and then using it for every feature file or extracting the login.feature file in others file rather than writing it for every other file.

Optimal solution and dynamic approach.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.